# Symfony 1.4 pass value from select without refreshing the page

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

i try to pass some value using Symfony 1.4 froms.

What i try to do is to pass value from SELECT to $variable without refreshing the page.

**CreateForm.php**

```
 $this->setWidget('cycle', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'label' => __( 'Cycle'),
        'choices' => $this->getCycles()
    ), array(
        'class' => 'inputText',
    )));

    $this->setValidator( 'cycle', new sfValidatorChoice( array(
        'required' => true,
        'choices' => array_keys( $this->getCycles())
    ), array(
    )));

    $this->setWidget('startCycle', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'label' => __( 'Start cycle' ),
        'choices' => ''
    ), array(
        'class' => 'inputTextshort',
    )));

    $this->setValidator( 'startCycle', new sfValidatorChoice( array(
        'required' => true,
        'choices' => ''
    ), array(
    )));

    $this->setWidget('endCycle', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'label' => __( 'End cycle' ),
        'choices' => ''
    ), array(
        'class' => 'inputTextshort',
    )));

    $this->setValidator( 'endCycle', new sfValidatorChoice( array(
        'required' => true,
        'choices' => ''
    ), array(
    )));
```

And some functions in **CreateForm.php:**

```
public function getCycles()
{
    return array(
        'DAY'   => 'DAY',
        'WEEK'  => 'WEEK',
        'MONTH' => 'MONTH',
        'YEAR'  => 'YEAR'
    );
}

public function getCyclesValues() {

    $arrCyclesValues = array(
        'DAY' => array(
            'start' => range(0,23),
            'end'   => range(0,23),
        ),
        'WEEK' => array(
            'start' => range(1,7),
            'end'   => range(1,7),
        ),
        'MONTH' => array(
            'start' => range(0,13),
            'end'   => range(0,13), 'can_be_empty' => true,
        ),
        'YEAR' => array(
            'start' => range(1,365),
            'end'   => range(1,365),
        ),
    );

    $start_day_cycyle   =  $arrCyclesValues['DAY']['start'];
    $stop_day_cycyle    =  $arrCyclesValues['DAY']['stop'];
    $start_week_cycyle  =  $arrCyclesValues['WEEK']['start'];
    $stop_week_cycyle   =  $arrCyclesValues['WEEK']['stop'];
    $start_month_cycyle =  $arrCyclesValues['MONTH']['start'];
    $stop_month_cycyle  =  $arrCyclesValues['MONTH']['stop'];
    $start_year_cycyle  =  $arrCyclesValues['YEAR']['start'];
    $stop_year_cycyle   =  $arrCyclesValues['YEAR']['stop'];

} 
public function getCycle() {


}
```

Basicly, view give me possibility to check one of four Cycles:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Con0u.png

When i check one of 4 values, i need to catch it without refreshing the page, and put it in some $variable to getCycle() method of CreateForm.php script.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to refresh part of your page with asynchronously.
So you'll have to use ajax.

Check the Day 18 part of the symfony1.4 tutorial.
That'll be a good starting point for what you're trying to do.